# Ray Casting for Points _Behind The Camera_

Tags: 3d, 2d, vectorization, trigonometry, raycasting

In a nutshell, I have a ray casting engine that uses rotation and some trigonometry, not vector math.  I'd like to add something that draws a line from any two points, but when one of those points is beyond the viewing plane, it goes bat-attack crazy (skyrocketing in terrible directions).

I haven't found any information that addresses this, but after looking around I'm suspicious that vector math might be the solution.  I'd like to avoid having to learn that or adapt the engine I've already made, especially if that isn't a solution or the only solution.

Here's some of the code I'm using:

```
pLoc is the x,y of the camera.
mLoc is the x,y of the point.
pRot is the rotation of the camera.
pHgh is the height (z) of the camera.
mHgh is the height (z) of the point.
```

On the grid x increases right, and y down. The grid size of the world is 128 pixels, and that's also the max height for the camera. The screen is 320 by 200 pixels.

```
xxx = pLoc.x-mLoc.x
yyy = pLoc.y-mLoc.y

moo = atan(xxx,-yyy)*(180/pi)
if moo < 0 then moo = moo+360

tmp = pRot+120-moo

if moo < 180 and pRot > 90 then
    tmp = tmp-360
else if moo > 180 and pRot > 270 then
    tmp = tmp-360
end if
```

Here, m is the distance from the camera to the point.

```
m = sqrt(power(pLoc.x-mLoc.x,2)+power(pLoc.y-mLoc.y,2))

boo = (tmp*-320/60)-160   -- this is x spot on screen.
poo = (64-pHgh+mHgh)*(300/(m))   -- this is the y spot.
goo = 128/m*2   -- this is a converted distance for whatever.
```

Again, if the point goes off-screen, its position goes crazy: it's not being represented correctly. If the answer really is that this would work with vector math, that's fine, but if there's any chance to even fake it in this approach, I'd very much like to discover it.

I almost forgot, there's also a bit of code in there to adjust for "fisheye" as well. If I'm remembering correctly it's applied to m (the distance), and uses cos.

Thanks. Hugs.

Comment: When you say you're not using vector math, you're really just arguing semantics. Clearly `(m)` is just the magnitude (length) of the the vector `v = mLoc - pLoc`. You might also consider using `atan2` rather than `atan`.

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks. I think i meant matrices though, when you add vectors together instead of using trig.  Also the language I'm using is for shockwave - that's actually an atan2 even though it doesn't say it.